# JSON file using sub queries and unions

Tags: json, sql-server, union

I know I've asked a similar question before but I wanted to make a clear post for what I'm trying to achieve. I've got most of it working as expected but I'm now at a point where I'm trying to use sub queries in order to format the JSON correctly. my query is below

```
SELECT
    
'Admin User TEST ONLY PLEASE IGNORE' AS AdditionalNotes,
    
   (
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                    ax.Acc_fault1 AS [atFault],
                    ax.Acc_desc1 AS [claimDetails],
                    ax.Acc_fault1 AS [claimStatus],
                    ax.Acc_type1 AS [claimType],
                    ax.Acc_date1 AS [dateOfClaim],
                    ax.Acc_injury1 AS [injuryInvolved],
                    ax.Acc_ncb1 AS [ncdAffected],
                    '' AS [settledDate],
                    ax.Acc_amt1 AS [totalCost]
            union
            SELECT 
                    ax.Acc_fault2 AS [atFault],
                    ax.Acc_desc2 AS [claimDetails],
                    ax.Acc_fault2 AS [claimStatus],
                    ax.Acc_type2 AS [claimType],
                    ax.Acc_date2 AS [dateOfClaim],
                    ax.Acc_injury2 AS [injuryInvolved],
                    ax.Acc_ncb2 AS [ncdAffected],
                    '' AS [settledDate],
                    ax.Acc_amt2 AS [totalCost]
            union
            SELECT 
                    ax.Acc_fault3 AS [atFault],
                    ax.Acc_desc3 AS [claimDetails],
                    ax.Acc_fault3 AS [claimStatus],
                    ax.Acc_type3 AS [claimType],
                    ax.Acc_date3 AS [dateOfClaim],
                    ax.Acc_injury3 AS [injuryInvolved],
                    ax.Acc_ncb3 AS [ncdAffected],
                    '' AS [settledDate],
                    ax.Acc_amt3 AS [totalCost]
            union
            SELECT  
                    ax.Acc_fault4 AS [atFault],
                    ax.Acc_desc4 AS [claimDetails],
                    ax.Acc_fault4 AS [claimStatus],
                    ax.Acc_type4 AS [claimType],
                    ax.Acc_date4 AS [dateOfClaim],
                    ax.Acc_injury4 AS [injuryInvolved],
                    ax.Acc_ncb4 AS [ncdAffected],
                    '' AS [settledDate],
                    ax.Acc_amt4 AS [totalCost]
            union
            SELECT  
                    ax.Acc_fault5 AS [atFault],
                    ax.Acc_desc5 AS [claimDetails],
                    ax.Acc_fault5 AS [claimStatus],
                    ax.Acc_type5 AS [claimType],
                    ax.Acc_date5 AS [dateOfClaim],
                    ax.Acc_injury5 AS [injuryInvolved],
                    ax.Acc_ncb5 AS [ncdAffected],
                    '' AS [settledDate],
                    ax.Acc_amt5 AS [totalCost]      
                )           
            AS [MotorRiskQueryInsuredPartyClaims]
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) AS  [MotorRiskQueryInsuredParties]

FROM

    dbo.icp_Daprospect AS p INNER JOIN
    dbo.icp_Dapolicy AS d ON p.Branch@ = d.Branch@ AND p.ClientRef@ = d.ClientRef@ LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.icp_DP_PC AS c ON p.Branch@ = c.Branch@ AND d.PolicyRef@ = c.PolicyRef@ LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.icp_DP_CF AS e ON p.Branch@ = e.Branch@ AND d.PolicyRef@ = e.PolicyRef@ LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.ic_DP_AX AS  ax ON P.Branch@ = ax.B@ AND ax.PolRef@ = d.PolicyRef@ LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.icp_QR54_VT AS i on e.Current_insurer_QR54_VTId = i.VTId
WHERE 
    
    d.PolicyRef@ = 'AAAA001PC1' AND
    d.Branch@ = 0


FOR JSON PATH
```

The output I'm getting:

```
{"AdditionalNotes":"Admin User TEST ONLY PLEASE IGNORE",
"MotorRiskQueryInsuredParties":[
    
    {"settledDate":"",
    "totalCost":0},

    {"atFault":"No Blame",
    "claimDetails":"Hit by TP in Rear",
    "claimStatus":"No Blame",
    "claimType":"Accident",
    "dateOfClaim":"2015-06-01T00:00:00",
    "injuryInvolved":"No",
    "ncdAffected":"No",
    "settledDate":"",
    "totalCost":50},

    {"atFault":"Yes",
    "claimDetails":"Hit TP in Rear",
    "claimStatus":"Yes",
    "claimType":"Accident",
    "dateOfClaim":"2012-09-01T00:00:00",
    "injuryInvolved":"No",
    "ncdAffected":"Yes",    
    "settledDate":"",
    "totalCost":50}]}
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
{"AdditionalNotes":"Admin User TEST ONLY PLEASE IGNORE",
    "MororRiskQueryInsuredParties": [
        {
            "MotorRiskInsuredPartyClaims": [
                {
                    "atFault": No Blame
                    "claimDetails": Hit by TP in Rear
                    "claimStatus": No Blame
                    "claimType": Accident
                    "dateOfClaim": 2015-06-01T00:00:00
                    "injuryInvolved": No
                    "ncdAffected": No
                    "settledDate": Null
                    "totalCost": 50
                },
                {
                    "atFault": Yes
                    "claimDetails": Hit TP in Rear
                    "claimStatus": Yes
                    "claimType": Accident
                    "dateOfClaim": 2012-09-01T00:00:00
                    "injuryInvolved": No
                    "ncdAffected": No
                    "settledDate": Null
                    "totalCost": 50
                },
                {
                    "atFault": null
                    "claimDetails": null
                    "claimStatus": null
                    "claimType": null
                    "dateOfClaim": null
                    "injuryInvolved": null
                    "ncdAffected": null
                    "settledDate": null
                    "totalCost": null
                },
                {
                    "atFault": null
                    "claimDetails": null
                    "claimStatus": null
                    "claimType": null
                    "dateOfClaim": null
                    "injuryInvolved": null
                    "ncdAffected": null
                    "settledDate": null
                    "totalCost": null
                },
                {
                    "atFault": null
                    "claimDetails": null
                    "claimStatus": null
                    "claimType": null
                    "dateOfClaim": null
                    "injuryInvolved": null
                    "ncdAffected": null
                    "settledDate": null
                    "totalCost": null
                }
            ],
```

for some reason I'm get a settled date and total cost appear at the top and then I see the results I'm expecting.

the JSON file also seems to be ignoring sub array text of "MotorRiskInsuredPartyClaims".

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong hopefully it's something simple.

Comment: The `{"settledDate":"","totalCost":0}` is probably an artifact of some of the total cost columns being 0-valued; the UNION combines them so you only see one such stub. If you want to see one per columnset, try UNION ALL instead. The other columns are all NULL-valued so they're omitted from the JSON result.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why it's not including the array heading "MotorRiskInsuredPartyClaims"? I'll have to try your other suggestions tomorrow when I'm back in the office. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, the `{"settledDate":"","totalCost":0}` stub is probably the result of a row in your table which has NULL values for one of the five columnsets (and a 0 value for totalCost, which might be the default value). If you want to omit the objects in this case, add a WHERE clause in the query that wraps the big union query to filter out the nulls.

Second, to get the wrapping right for JSON, I was able to get your desired output by specifying the ROOT option to FOR JSON PATH:

```
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('MotorRiskQueryInsuredPartyClaims')
```

Without this option, FOR JSON PATH does not wrap the object under a root key, so your second "AS" was just re-aliasing the column name.